# NSTableView get indexPath having the cell

Tags: swift, xcode, nstableview

With `UITableView` it's pretty easy to find the `indexPath` based on a cell using

```
tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
```

but on MacOS this method does not exist unfortunately. 
My use case is the following: 
I have a button in the `Cell View` and upon click I call the delegated `ViewController` to do stuff. Now I have the instance of the cell, what I want to obtain is its row (position) in the `NSTableView`. How can I obtain it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In macOS use a view based table view, create an standard `IBAction` for the button and get the row with `row(for view:`

> ```
> func row(for view: NSView) -> Int
> ```
>
> Returns the index of the row for the specified view.

A view based table view is much more versatile and much easier to handle.

Comment: To elaborate, row is an instance method. To cast the sender (NSButton) as NSView, it is enough to do tableView.row(for: sender!)

Answer (score 0):

To add a specific case to @vadian's answer:

I had the same case as @rdid4, but with multiple tableViews. I entered up with this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {

   switch  (tableView){

   let cellView = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier("projectCell1"), owner: self) as? ProjectCell

   if (tableColumn?.identifier)!.rawValue == "projectColumn1" {
      let cellView = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier("projectCell1"), owner: self) as? ProjectCell
```

The cellView has an inline NSButton

```
 cellView?.statusButton.action = #selector(projectStatusChanged(sender:))
 cellView?.statusButton.tag = 1
```

The cell tag showed me the NSTableView I needed to address (I have two in the project).

Then in

```
@objc func projectStatusChanged(sender: NSButton) {


        switch  (sender.tag){

        case 1:
             projectRowIndex = projectTable1.row(for: sender)
           ....

        case 2:
             projectRowIndex = projectTable2.row(for: sender)

default...
```

I hope this helps others..